# Convert binary to uniqueidentifier in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following code that converts Unique-identifier to Binary:

```
CAST(GUID AS BINARY(16))
```

which results in this `'0x56B3C0955919CD40931F550749A83AF3'`

Now, I want to convert this (i.e. the **binary string value** `'0x56B3C0955919CD40931F550749A83AF3'`) to Unique-Identifier.

Any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uh, just convert it back?

```
DECLARE @n UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

SELECT @n;
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), @n);
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, CONVERT(BINARY(16), @n));
```

If you have a binary value like `0x56B3C0955919CD40931F550749A83AF3`, stop putting it into quotes when trying to convert it. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 0x56B3C0955919CD40931F550749A83AF3);
```

Isn't this the result you're after?

```
95C0B356-1959-40CD-931F-550749A83AF3
```

Comment: Sure, but my problem is that I can't use @n in the last line. I must use the string value of the binary which is '0x27777EDFC1533B4388B01EACB8ED7102'. So, if you do this: SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, CONVERT(BINARY(16), '0x27777EDFC1533B4388B01EACB8ED7102')); You get wrong value.

Comment: It's a Binary. No quotes needed. Thank you very much for the help.